# Android Zxing camera not working when backpress

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm facing an issue on my ZXing QR code scanner. The issue is when i press the back button from webpage or from new activity, the scanner will stop working and not be able to scan anything. Can anyone tell me where is my mistakes? :x
Thanks in advance.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import android.net.Uri;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
    }

    public void scan(View view) {
        zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

        if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText()).matches()) {
            // Open URL
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
        if(result.getText().equals("Welcome to Booth A")) {
            // Open nextActivity
            Intent Quiz1 = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(Quiz1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onBackPressed` method in `ScannerActivity`. You can do it like

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //do something
}
```

The default method call destroys current fragment or activity. Which goes through `onPause`, in which you stopped camera by doing `zXingScannerView.stopCamera();`.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the problem

Comment: can you share your Code that you solve it .. because my issue is when i use backpress app just close completely Thanks @Tan Kahseng